# Wordpress Smart Iframe Browser

Tags: plugins

How to browse other website without leaving domain?

for ex. my website is websites1.com and i want to someone to goto website2.com but doamin name in address bar must be website1.com only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you on track...

```
<iframe src="javascript:void(0);" frameborder="0" style="display:none;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;" id="fullsizeframe"></iframe>

<a href="http://website2.com" onclick="loadfullsize(this.href);">Website 2</a>

<script>function loadfullsize(url) {
    fullsizeframe = document.getElementById('fullsizeframe');
    fullsizeframe.href = url; fullsizeframe.style.height = window.clientHeight;
    return false;    
} </script>
```

Note the problem here is you have to insert the iframe HTML directly after the `<body>` tag (and have no CSS width rules on the body tag) for this to work or the iframe width may be limited to less that full width if inside other containing divs etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to clarify more about your exact requirement.

However as per what's apparent, you simply want to use an iframe inside your content to show any other website. There are various ways to do that manually or through plugins, e.g.: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-wrapper/

I hope it helps.